# Is is more efficient to query multiple ElasticSearch indices at once or one big index

Tags: elasticsearch, query-optimization

I have an ElasticSearch cluster and my system handles events coming from an API.
Each event is a document stored in an index and I create a new index per source (the company calling the API). Sources come and go, so I have new sources every week and most sources become inactive after a few weeks. Each source send between 100k and 10M new events every day.

Right now my indices are named *api-events-sourcename*

The documents contain a datetime field and most of my queries look like "fetch the data for that source between those dates.

I frequently use Kibana and I have configured a filter that matches all my indices (*api-events-**) at once, and I then add terms to filter a specific source and specific days.

My requests can be slow at times and they tend to slow down the ingestion of new data.

Given that workflow, should I see any performance benefits to create an index per source and per day, instead of the index per source only that I use today ?

Are there other easy tricks to avoid putting to much strain on the cluster ?

Thanks!

Comment: what is difference in size of indices and number of document between per source and daily indices?

Comment: Let's say a source sends 21M events for ~3 weeks, that would be 1M documents per index with per day/per source index vs 21m with only per source index.

Comment: I seriously recommend to use per source indices. 1m documents is very small indices. and you will encounter more issue in future.

Comment: What kind of issues would I be facing in the future with per source/per day indices ?

Comment: heap usage and I/O disk issue. elasticsearch have limit for number of shards per node. (1024) .